# Showing UINavigationController in a Modal segue (ViewController)?

Tags: ios, rotation, modal-dialog, modalviewcontroller

I have now been stuck on this problem for more then 2 weeks! In my project, I have 1 single ViewController(slide) I want to enable both landscape and portrait in. The rest of all controllers/views(slides) I want to enable portrait-mode only.

The tricky part is, the "ViewController" I am referring to is connected to both NavigationControllers and TabBarControllers. See the scheme below where the ViewController I want to enable both landscape/portrait is named: ***ReferredViewController.***

**TabBarController ----> NavigationController ----> FristViewController --(push event)--> *ReferredViewController***

So far I have tried to make a ***CATEGORY*** for both NavigationControllers and TabBarControllers. But since my NavigationControllers and TabBarControllers are placed at the very start of the project this will set the rules for the whole project. My ReferredViewController is placed at the end or in the middle of the projects "storyboard". I have tried to set the rules by code aswell for the single ReferredViewController without any success.

My best shot is to change the event between FirstViewController and ReferredViewController from "push" to "modal". ReferredViewController can then rotate both portrait/landscape and the rest of the project is locked in portrait. BUT, as you may know all navigations (NavigationBar) will be lost and the user will become stuck at that single slide.

So I am trying to enable the NavigationBar with the following code example in the *ReferredViewController.m file:*

```
ShowTaskViewController *detailViewController = [[ShowTaskViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]     initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES  completion:nil];
[navController release];
[detailViewController release];
```

But ofc nothing happens and I am back to square one again :O. FML!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to over ride UITaBarController because it is you base view controller. I have done this for my navigation controller. Tell me if this helped.

```
@interface UINavigationController (Autorotation)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation;
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate;
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations;
@end

@implementation UINavigationController (Autorotation)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{

if ([self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[MWPhotoBrowser class]] || [self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[ZoomPictureViewController class]]) {
    return YES;
}
return  (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{

    if ([self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[MWPhotoBrowser class]] ||     [self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[ZoomPictureViewController class]]) {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController 
                                             animated:YES  
                                           completion:nil];
```

you are conflating two UIViewController instance methods:

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent 
                     animated:(BOOL)flag 
                   completion:(void (^)(void))completion

- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController 
                          animated:(BOOL)animated
```

The first of these is now the standard, the second method was deprecated in ios6.

Also the presenting view controller should be self (the ReferredViewController), not self's navigationController.

Your presented view controller can dismiss itself thus

```
 [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES 
                                                     completion:(void (^)(void))completion];
```

But take a look at fibnochi's answer, it may be a better way for you to achieve your result.